# What does "ghosts" mean here?

Tags: meaning

Pere Tanguy speaks about the doctor who treated Vincent,
when he was alive:

> Pere Tanguy: I understand he's still close to the Van Gogh family.
> Maybe you should ask him why Vincent did it.
>
> Armand: It's my father who wanted to know why.
> I just wanted to deliver this letter for him.
>
> Pere Tanguy: The Van Gogh's are only **ghosts** in Paris now.

What does "ghosts" mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ghosts" implies that there are no members of the Van Gogh family remaining or that the Van Gogh family has become much smaller. They either moved away or died off (the more literal reference).

Usage of "ghost" -- when not referring to departed souls -- indicates small, faint or missing.

Merriam-Webster comes close with:

```
4a: a faint shadowy trace
a ghost of a smile
b: the least bit
not a ghost of a chance
```